# My function with scanner crashes instead of returning input number (java)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I created a function that asks user for a number. The function checks if it is a positive integer and if it is an integer at all, and should return that number.

The program crashes every time if the user puts in a positive integer. I am new to eclipse IDE and don't know where to look for a log of runtime errors.

I already tried return height.nextInt() and deleted the z variable, didn't work.
(This function is for a bigger program that eventually prints out a pyramid.)

```
package skener;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyClass 
{
    public static int z = 0;
    public static int userInput()
    {
        Scanner height = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please choose a number: ");
        while(!height.hasNextInt() || (height.nextInt() < 0))
        {
            //height = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Wrong number, try again: ");
            height = new Scanner(System.in);

        }
        z = height.nextInt();
        height.close();
        return z;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(userInput());
    }
}
```

If user input is 3, I expect to get return 3, to use in another program. Instead the program simply terminates and the terminal doesn't provide any error messages and doesn't return the input.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Could you please add your stack trace with the complete error ?

Comment: The runtime errors will appear in the console, in the same place where you're entering numbers. What do you enter, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? This program does not crash. It probably doesn't do what you want, but you should precisely tell us what you want and what you get instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your program should be like below,

```
Scanner height = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please choose a number: ");
        z = height.nextInt();
        while((z < 0))
        {
            System.out.println("Wrong number, try again: ");
            z = height.nextInt();

        }

        return z;
```

here we are getting the integer value in z and we are checking the condition and returning if it's positive or we will ask user to enter again. Please use import scanner module in import java.util.Scanner;

Comment: Also, it would be great if you could explain him what is wrong in his code and why it didn't work!

Comment: And you should **not** close the scanner when reading from the console.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the program is also supposed to re-prompt for input if the input is anything other than int. In your version if the input is a char, the program crashes.

what do you mean use import scanner module?

Comment: Yes correct you can do something like this to check the input is number or not,
Scanner height = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please choose a number: ");
        while(!height.hasNextInt()) { //here this will check valid integers
         System.out.println("please enter a number");
         height.next(); //this is important
        }
        z = height.nextInt();
        while((z < 0))
        {
            System.out.println("Wrong number, try again: ");
            z = height.nextInt();

        }
        return z;

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want.

```java
      Scanner height = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Please choose a number: ");
      int z = -1; // default value means no valid integer entered.
      // ensure that the next value is an int and if so. 
      // it is >= 0.

      while (height.hasNextInt() && (z = height.nextInt()) < 0) {
         System.out.println("Wrong number, try again: ");
      }
      // Display the value
      System.out.println("z = " + z);
      // and if in a method, return it.
      return z;
```

Your solution was very close.  You should not have `closed` the `scanner` because that also closes the `Console input` which you would not be able to re-open and read from.

And as you specified in your original code, if you don't check for a non-numeric value, before getting an int, your code will throw an exception.